# Nginx redirect and preserve url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I would like to redirect all urls to the directory root on a server running Nginx, while preserving the original path in the url.

For example: domain.com/test redirects to domain.com/ and its index file but preserves /test in the url path.

With Apache, I believe it would look something like this in the .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.html
</ifModule>
```

Any ideas on how to do this with Nginx?

Comment: `.htaccess` is for Apache. Nginx uses internal configuration for things like that.

Comment: Have re-worded it, question remains but for a redirects.conf file

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Answer (score 0):

You can add this config to nginx for equivalent:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```